# Current best practice/options for peer to peer payments processing

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments, payment-processing

I was hoping to be pointed in the right direction before starting to dig in deep.

What is the current best practice to have peer to peer transaction trigger an event (cloud function). For example, in case of "AirBnb", a peer pays another peer an agreed upon amount and door lock automatically un-locks. Or better yet, as soon as door is unlocked a pre-set function transfers money from one peer to another based on agreed upon price/contract.

It appears like [PayPal's Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) would have worked, but it currently does not support new applications. Do any digital wallet providers (Venmo, CahApp, Apple Pay, Google Pay etc) have of such functionality? Square, Stripe etc all work great for merchant-peer but it seem to be [tougher to find options for peer to peer](https://medium.com/@rohitsinha/search-for-p2p-payment-apis-1ce20a729451). If that is still the case, what might be some ideas to consider?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

AirBnB essentially uses PayPal Checkout to accept payments, and the PayPal [Payouts API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-a-paypal-business-account) to send payouts to receivers later. There may be a little more to it, as they're a giant with a direct partner relationship with PayPal and potential access to bespoke thing--but that's the essential structure of what they do, and what anyone else could do.

You would need to contact PayPal to find out if Payouts is acceptable and will be approved by them for your own particular business use case. No one else can tell you this.

---

For facilitating direct payments from one peer to another, you can set the `payee` parameter in an ordinary PayPal checkout. This doesn't give you any gating control over the payment.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/

Comment: Thank you for you reply and direction. I took some time to poke around the link you provided and think about your comments. I think a workaround that may work for myself is actually setting up a merchant account, peers can "deposit money" through either Paypal/Stripe and have a balance to use within an application. Each user within the application trades services with their balance which equals the deposited amounts. At any point one peer can request a payout, at that point the merchant will pay that peer. This in theory should allow seamless/low cost transactions. We will see!